# Find a proof for the following tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, hilbert-calculus

I was introduced to Axiomatic Theory in last class and I need to know how to solve this kind of problem in the midterm next week. However, I have no  idea how to solve these kind of problems. We had no practice in class and we won't have any, so I'm very desperate.

I need to find a proof for $\alpha \rightarrow (\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \lnot \beta)$ using the usual axioms and Modus Ponens

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus and if that does not help, come back with specific questions. Teaching an entire course through a forum is not realistic.

Comment: I know the axioms, I know the rule of modus ponens. All I'm asking for is a proof for the statement

Comment: There is no such thing as “the usual axioms.” You need to give them.

Comment: I meant the Jan Łukasiewicz axioms

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Well, Jan Lukasiewicz's preferred axiom set was {CCpqCCqrCpr, CCNppp, CpCNpq}.  Hardly anyone else has ever used that axiom set.  Lukasiewicz found many other axiom sets for propositional calculus, including a single axiom of 23 letters (which was a single axiom, but there was no sufficient indication of how to derive another axiom set in the literature until Larry Wos's work in the 90s/2000s).  So, you might want to spell out those axioms.

Comment: They're right below AlexanderJ93's answer

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Deduction Theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Use importation:

$$ p\to(q\to r) \vdash ((p\wedge q)\to r) $$

So,

$$ \alpha\to(\neg\alpha \to \neg\beta) \vdash ((\alpha\wedge\neg\alpha)\to\neg\beta) \vdash (F\to\neg\beta) \vdash T $$

Comment: I'm supposed to only work under the  Jan Łukasiewicz axioms and Modus Ponens

Comment: Yes, I didn't see your comment until after I posted. I will update.

Comment: Thanks. I've been at it for over 30 minutes now

Comment: To be clear, you mean: [1] A→(B→A), [2] (A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C)), [3] (¬A→¬B)→(B→A), plus Modus Ponens?

Comment: The last one is changed to $(\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \lnot \beta) \rightarrow ((\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow \alpha))$. I don't know why the last one was changed

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio The last one wasn't used as an axiom by Lukasiewicz.  Sp far as I know, it doesn't appear as an axiom until Mendelsohn (though Jaskowski implied it as such much earlier).

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio I can't get a solution right now... may come back to it later if I have time, but if you do get a solution, be sure to post it here!